# How to distinctly count customer IDs that visited a store in a given quarter only if the same customer ID visited in the previous quarter

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table

```
+-----------+----------+--------+-------+---------+
|Customer ID|Visit Date|Category|Product|Served by|
+-----------+----------+--------+-------+---------+
|1001       |03/17/2019|A       |P11    |Jone Doe |
|1003       |03/17/2019|D       |P12    |Jone Doe |
|1006       |03/15/2019|C       |P13    |Jone Doe |
|1009       |03/10/2019|G       |P14    |Jone Doe |
|1011       |12/12/2018|H       |P15    |Foo Bar  |
|1003       |11/11/2018|D       |P16    |Foo Bar  |
|1006       |09/10/2018|C       |P17    |Foo Bar  |
|1009       |10/10/2018|G       |P18    |Foo Bar  |
+-----------+----------+--------+-------+---------+
```

there are 4 customers but only 2 (1003 and 1009) visited in the previous quarter.

I used DATESINPERIOD but it counts all distinctly between the preceding quarters (I have a designated date table).

1st approach

```
customers_count =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT[Customer ID],
    DATESINPERIOD (
        'Calendar'[Date],
        ENDOFQUARTER ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        -2,
        QUARTER
    )
)
```

2nd approach

```
customers_count 2Q =
VAR customers_count_1 =
    DISTINCT ( FILTER ( VALUES ( Orders[Customer ID] ) ) )
VAR customers_count_2 =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( FILTER ( VALUES ( Orders[Customer ID] ) ) ),
        DATEADD ( 'Calendar'[Date], -1, QUARTER )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( customers_count_1, customers_count_2 ) )
```

The expected count is 2 for the last quarter.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach looks reasonable. Try it without `DISTINCT` and `FILTER`.

```
customers_count 2Q =
VAR customers_count_1 =
    VALUES ( Orders[Customer ID] )
VAR customers_count_2 =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Orders[Customer ID] ),
        DATEADD ( 'Calendar'[Date], -1, QUARTER )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( customers_count_1, customers_count_2 ) )
```

The `VALUES` function returns a list of distinct values of its column argument that are within its filter context.

Comment: thanks for quick response @Alexis, this returned only one column (customer ID) -because of  **VALUES** ,but I need other columns as well

Comment: Your question just asked for a count of distinct `Customer ID`. What are you doing with the other columns?

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, other columns are used for filtering in other measures

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you want to filter the `Customer ID` by other columns, then wrap `VALUES` with `CALCULATETABLE` an add whatever filtering you'd like. If other columns and measures are directly relevant to the question, then you need to explain that in your post instead of making vague comments about them.